# How to fix this dual cone?

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis, convex-cone, dual-cone

Consider the following cone:

$$\mathbb{G}_n=\Bigg\{\,(x\oplus\theta\oplus\kappa) \in\mathbb{R}^n\oplus\mathbb{R}_+\oplus\mathbb{R}_+\,\colon \theta\sum_{i\in [n]}\exp\bigg(\frac{-x_i}{\theta}\bigg)\leq\kappa \Bigg\}.$$

Where $0\exp(\frac{\alpha}{0})=0$ for each $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

I am trying to calculate the dual of $\mathbb{G}_n$. A similar result is presented in https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00006861/document Sec 6.3 and my attempt is to adapt it to my case. However, I found the following problems:

1- While considering the case where $\theta=0$, we still have that $(x,0,\kappa)\in\mathbb{G}_n$ for each $(x,\kappa)\in\mathbb{R}^n\oplus\mathbb{R}_+$. Because $x$ is not necessairly nonnegative, I couldn't obtain any corresponding sign constraints on $x^\ast$ and $\kappa^\ast$ (besides $x^\ast=0$ and $\kappa^\ast\geq0$).

2- While minimizing a single term of the summation, I would obtain that $t_i=−\log(\frac{|x_i^\ast|}{\kappa^\ast})$ because there is no $\log$ for negative numbers, is this right?

3- Why is the minimum equal to zero when $\kappa^\ast=0$?

4- The two final cases colapse and then we obtain that the minimum is $−x_i^\ast\log(\frac{x_i^\ast}{\kappa^\ast})$ either way?

5- Finally, we conclude that $x^\ast\in$?, $\kappa^\ast\in$? and $\theta^\ast\geq\sum_i x_i^\ast\log(\frac{x_i^\ast}{\kappa^\ast})−x_i^\ast$. Right?

Can anyone help me to fix these?

Comment: What does $\oplus$ mean?

Comment: It is a cartesian product of vector spaces that carries their structure. More formally, if $V$ and $W$ are  Euclidean spaces we define the direct sum of $V$ and $W$ as the vector space $V\oplus W=\{v\oplus w\,\colon v\in V\text{ and } w\in W\}$
where we consider, for each $v_1\oplus w_1, v_2\oplus w_2\in V\oplus W$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$,
$v_1\oplus w_1 + v_2\oplus w_2= (v_1+_Vv_2)\oplus (w_1+_Ww_2) $ and $\alpha(v_1\oplus w_2)=\alpha v_1\oplus\alpha w_1.$ Also, we consider $\langle v_1\oplus w_1,v_2\oplus w_2\rangle=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle_V +\langle w_1,w_2\rangle_W$.

Comment: How do you interpret the constraining equation when $\theta = 0$? I am assuming that by cone you mean that $t x \in C$ for all $t \ge 0, x \in C$.

Comment: @copper.hat, thanks for pointing this out, I will edit my question to make it clearer. And you are right about the definition of a cone (indeed your definition is for closed cones but it is the case).